# Is it possible to have multiple classes (be it UITableViewCell or UIViewController) share a single xib in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xib

I have an xib which is already associated with a class. When I created a UITableViewCell in my xamarin ios project it generated an xib along with it. Now I need to create another UITableViewCell, where I want to reuse the already existing xib. Is it possible? When I tried extending the already existing TableCell am always getting a cast exception in my project. It would be helpful if I could get this cast exception sorted out or get the existing xib to work with my new class.

Comment: Hey, did you solve the issue?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Since you said its not possible I went with different classes and their own corresponding xibs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple classes share a single xib in Xamarin.iOS?

A xib can only has one corresponding class. And as this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/xib-code-generation#cross-xib-class-usage) said ,Working with .xib files is not currently supported in Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio.

Apple recommended developer to use storyboard instead of xib.Here is a [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRjM04HKCW4) use native iOS.You can refer to it.